# Conditional fields for the field type 'managed_file' is not working in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, forms, files

I have two radio buttons

- Enter The Text
- Upload a Text File

If user select the 1st option, a field of type **'textfield'** will appear & if they select the 2nd option, a field of type **'managed_file'** will appear.

 But this code with working fine for **textfield** but not working for **managed_file**
 Now, how to implement conditional fields in Drupal 8 ?

This is my D8 code.

```
    $form['field_type'] = array(
    '#type'    => 'radios',
    '#options' => array_combine( array(t('Enter The Text'), t('Upload a Text File'))
                                 array(t('Enter The Text'), t('Upload a Text File'))
                                ),
    '#title'   => t('Choose entry type.')
  );

  $form['imgurl'] = array(
    '#type'          => 'textfield',
    '#title'         => t('Enter the text'),
    '#states'        => array(
      'visible'      => array(
        ':input[name="field_type"]' => array('value' => t('Enter The Text')),
      ),
    ),
  );

  $form['file'] = array(
    '#title'              => t('Choose Text File'),
    '#type'               => 'managed_file',
    '#progress_indicator' => 'throbber',
    '#progress_message'   => NULL,
    '#upload_location'    => 'public://files/',
    '#states'             => array(
      'visible'           => array(
        ':input[name="field_type"]' => array('value' => t('Upload a Text File')),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, if this as anything to do with managed files, but I think `#options` should look like this:

```
'#options' => array(
  'text' => t('Enter The Text'),
  'upload' => t('Upload a Text File'),
),
```

and in `#states` the options key, not the translatable value:

```
'#states' => array(
  'visible' => array(
    ':input[name="field_type"]' => array('value' => 'text'),
  ),
),
```

If it has something to do with managed_file, then this old issue is back:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1118016

You can check this by changing temporarily `managed_file` to `file`.

Comment: Tried your solution. Having the same problem. 'managed_file' type field is not hiding on selecting the other option.

Comment: There was an issue with this, see the edited answer.